# How to export data from LinqPAD as JSON?

Tags: json, linqpad

I want to create a JSON file for use as part of a simple web prototyping exercise. LinqPAD is perfect for accessing the data from my DB in just the shape I need, however I cannot get it out as JSON very easily.

I don't really care what the schema is, because I can adapt my JavaScript to work with whatever is returned.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A more fluent solution is to add the following methods to the "My Extensions" File in Linqpad:

```
public static String DumpJson<T>(this T obj)
{
    return
        obj
        .ToJson()
        .Dump();
}

public static String ToJson<T>(this T obj)
{
    return
        new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
        .Serialize(obj);
}
```

Then you can use them like this in any query you like:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
.Select(i =>
    new
    {
        Index = i,
        IndexTimesTen = i * 10,
    })
.DumpJson();
```

I added "ToJson" separately so it can be used in with "Expessions".

Comment: That is nicer once it's set up. Thanks very much! I hope the author includes this in LinqPAD by default. Note to others, you will have to add the `System.Web.Extensions.dll` to the _My Extensions_ document, as described in my answer.

Comment: This fails if there is a relationship on the datatype with: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'LINQPad.User.YourType' :(

Answer (score 11):

This is not directly supported, and I have opened a feature request [here](http://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4182940-support-export-of-query-results-to-json). Vote for it if you would also find this useful.

A workaround for now is to do the following:

- Set the language to *C# Statement(s)*
- Add an assembly reference (press <kbd>F4</kbd>) to `System.Web.Extensions.dll`
- In the same dialog, add a namespace import to `System.Web.Script.Serialization`
- Use code like the following to dump out your query as JSON

```
new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(query).Dump();
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the easiest solution to implement.

Comment: The straightforward solution.

Comment: Nice approach. Let me add, I had to append a `.select(...)` along with a `new {...}` like `var query = myTable.Select(s=> new {s.Id, s=>s.MyField1});` otherwise it would throw *`A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'LINQPad.User.myTable'`*

Answer (score 11):

There's a solution with **Json.NET** since it does indented formatting, and renders Json dates properly. Add Json.NET from NuGet, and refer to *Newtonsoft.Json.dll* to your “*My Extensions*” query and as well the following code :

```
public static object DumpJson(this object value, string description = null)
{
    return GetJson(value).Dump(description);
}

private static object GetJson(object value)
{
    object dump = value;

    var strValue = value as string;
    if (strValue != null)
    {
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strValue);
        dump = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    }
    else
    {
        dump = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    }

    return dump;
}
```

Use **.DumpJson()** as `.Dump()` to render the result. It's possible to override more `.DumpJson()` with different signatures if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 4.47, LINQPad has the ability to export JSON built in. Combined with the new `lprun.exe` utility, it can also satisfy your needs.

http://www.linqpad.net/lprun.aspx